# infinite series question involving sigma

Tags: sequences-and-series

how to find out the sum of infinite series question
$$\displaystyle\mathop{\sum^{\infty}\sum^{\infty}\sum^{\infty}}_{i=0\ j=0\ k=0\ i\neq j\neq k}\frac{1}{3^i}\cdot \frac{1}{3^j}\cdot \frac{1}{3^k}$$

the answer in the book is given to be $\displaystyle \frac{81}{208}$.

Answer (score 1):

Fist we will calculate the sum without any restriction. So  $$\displaystyle\mathop{\sum^{\infty}\sum^{\infty}\sum^{\infty}}_{i=0\ j=0\ k=0\ }\frac{1}{3^i}\cdot \frac{1}{3^j}\cdot \frac{1}{3^k} = \sum^{\infty}_{i=0}\left(\frac{1}{3^i}\right)^3 = \left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}}\right)^3 = \frac{27}{8}.$$

Now for the first sum we have to remove all the cases when $i=j=k$ and also remove

all the cases when any $2$ of them equal but not equal to other variable (say $i=j\neq k$)

$\bullet\; $ If $i=j=k\;,$ Then $$\displaystyle\mathop{\sum^{\infty}\sum^{\infty}\sum^{\infty}}_{i=0\ j=0\ k=0}\frac{1}{3^i}\cdot \frac{1}{3^j}\cdot \frac{1}{3^k} = \sum^{\infty}_{i=0}\frac{1}{3^{3i}} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{27}} = \frac{27}{26}.$$

$\bullet\; $ If $i=j\neq k\;,$ Then $$\displaystyle\mathop{\sum^{\infty}\sum^{\infty}\sum^{\infty}}_{i=0\ j=0\ k=0}\frac{1}{3^i}\cdot \frac{1}{3^j}\cdot \frac{1}{3^k} = \left(\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}\frac{1}{3^{2i}}\right)\cdot \left(\sum^{\infty}_{k=0\;\; k\neq i}\frac{1}{3^{2i}}\right)$$

So we get $$= \left(\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}\frac{1}{3^{2i}}\right)\cdot \left[\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{3^{i}}\right] = \frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{9}{8}-\frac{27}{26} = \frac{135}{8\times 26}$$

So there are three type of such pair in second Case, So we will multiply second case by $3$

So Required Sum is $$ = \frac{27}{8}-\frac{27}{26}-3\times \frac{135}{8\times 26} = \frac{81}{208}$$

Comment: =what is the condition on ∑∞∑∞∑∞i=0 j=0 k=0 1/3i⋅1/3j⋅1/3k and how do you proceeded to this step.can you explain me in somewhat detail.